# Reference div id in one views folder from a separate views folder

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I am appending code to a div block from a partial using unobtrusive javascript.  Inside my views there are two folders called videos and posts.  In the the video folder is a show.html.erb file.  In this show.html.erb file there's a form to allow a user to create a post.  The form attribute remote is set to true and I want the post that gets submitted by the form to be loaded onto the page (the same show.html.erb page) without having to refresh (AJAX functionality).  When the form is submitted it is sent to the create method of the posts controller.  In this method there's a

```
format.js
```

that calls views > posts > create.js.erb.
The code I have written for this file so far is:

```
$('#comments').append('<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'posts'))%>');
```

comments is the div id for a block in the show.html.erb file.  The partial 'posts' is inside the posts folder (views > posts > _posts).  Right now this is not working properly and I believe its because the create.js.erb file is in a separate folder from the file whose div id its trying to reference.  How do I get the javascript code from the posts folder to reference the div block inside the video show file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being relatively new to rails and even newer to jquery I had an issue in identifying my problem.  I thought that because my jquery code was in a separate folder from the div I wanted to reference that the code I had above wouldn't work properly.  The answer (as I found out) is that as long as the div and the jquery are in the same DOM the reference works fine.  I had a bug somewhere else in my code that was preventing the AJAX request from functioning normally.  After fixing that my jquery code works as intended.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking but you can pass a partial the full path like this:

```
 $('#next_videos').empty().append('<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'videos/partial_name'))%>');
```

Comment: That's not what I need.  I need to modify the '#next_videos' part of the code because next_videos is a div id that's in a separate views folder from the javascript code above.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sorry, then you probably need to redefine your question because I'm not sure at all what you're asking. Sorry.